# How to delete string between two different signs in python

Tags: python, regex

Given text with some phrases between `/* */`, I would like to remove the strings/phrases that are inside.

**For example:**

```
aaaabbbbb /*ppppqqqqrrrsss sstttuuu*/cccccddddeee
```

*desired output:*

```
aaaabbbbb /**/cccccddddeee
```

I tried to use `re.sub(r'(\/*{2,3}[\s\n]*)(?:.*?[\s\n]*)*([\n\s]*\/*{2,3})` from python's REGEX, but the * symbol isn't recognized.

Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Comment: `*` is a regex special character so it needs to be escaped if you want a literal `\*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?<=\/\*)[\s\S]*?(?=\*\/)`

This regex uses a positive lookbehind to assert the presence of a preceding `/*` and a positive lookahead to assert the presence of a trailing `*/`, and between the two captures any characters across any number of lines.

As pointed out in the comments, `*` is a special regex character, and needs to be escaped with a backslash, like `\*`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3AtWIy/1/)

---

The python code is as follows:

```py
import re

text = "aaaabbbbb /*ppppqqqqrrrsss\n\nss/tt*tu/uu*/cccccddddeee"

print(re.sub('(?<=\/\*)[\s\S]*?(?=\*\/)', '', text))
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/AntiqueLeadingSystem)

Comment: OOOh my God, yes, I wasn't finding a way to escape the *. It worked. Thank you. =)